# c,equality operator on unsigned char and char

Tags: c, char, operators, equality, unsigned

why can I get **"x==y"** when I compare **int** to **unsigned int**

then,why can I get **"a!=b"** when I compare **char** to **unsigned char**,although they do have the same bit pattern "**0xff**"

when applying equality operator,does it take variable type into consideration?

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    unsigned int x = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    int y = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    printf("unsigned int x = 0xFFFFFFFF;\n");
    printf("int y = 0xFFFFFFFF;\n");
    if (x < 0)
        printf("x < 0\n");
    else
        printf("x > 0\n");
    if (y < 0)
        printf("y < 0\n");
    else
        printf("y > 0\n");
    if(x==y)
        printf("x==y\n\n");
    ///////////-- char --////////////////////////
    unsigned char a = 0xFF;
    char b = 0xFF;    
    printf("unsigned char a = 0xFF\n");
    printf("char b = 0xFF\n");
    if (a < 0)
        printf("a < 0\n");
    else
        printf("a > 0\n");
    if (b < 0)
        printf("b < 0\n");
    else
        printf("b > 0\n");
    if(a==b)
        printf("a==b\n");   
    else
        printf("a!=b\n");

}
```

output:

```
unsigned int x = 0xFFFFFFFF;
int y = 0xFFFFFFFF;
x > 0
y < 0
x==y

unsigned char a = 0xFF
char b = 0xFF
a > 0
b < 0
a!=b
```

Comment: http://icecube.wisc.edu/~dglo/c_class/promo_conv.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the C11 ISO/IEC 9899:201x standard:

> Otherwise,  if  the  operand  that  has  unsigned  integer  type  has 
>   rank  greater  or equal  to  the  rank  of  the  type  of  the  other 
>   operand,  then  the  operand  with signed  integer  type  is 
>   converted  to  the  type  of  the  operand  with  unsigned integer
>   type.

The promotion is applied on  `int y = 0xFFFFFFFF` before comparing with `unsigned int x = 0xFFFFFFFF`. Promoting `int y` to `unsigned int` will keep the value 0xFFFFFFFF, which causes `x == y`.
On the other hand :

> If  an int can  represent  all  values  of  the  original  type  (as 
>   restricted  by  the  width,  for  a bit-field),  the  value  is 
>   converted  to  an int ; otherwise,  it  is  converted  to  an unsigned
>   int . These  are  called  the integer promotions . All  other 
>   types  are  unchanged  by  the integer promotions. The  integer 
>   promotions  preserve  value  including  sign.   As  discussed 
>   earlier,  whether  a ‘‘plain’’ char is treated as signed is
>   implementation-defined.

Which means `unsigned char a = 0xFF` & `char b = 0xFF` are both converted to `signed int` before comparison. However converting `b` will lead to sign extension which means value of `b` is extended to `0xFFFFFFFF == -1` causing `int a = 255` to be greater than `int b = -1`.

Answer (score 2):

because of **promotion**.

**char** or **short** type will be promoted to **int** before any comparison.

so

`unsigned char a = 0xFF` will be promoted to 0x000000FF(255)

`char b = 0xFF` will be promoted to 0xFFFFFFFF(-1)

they are not equal.

Answer (score 1):

C generally promotes integral values to `int`s for operations. For `unsigned char u = 0xFFu;` and `signed char s = 0xFF;`, in evaluating `u == s` `s` is sign-extended and `u` is not so it is interpreted as `0xFF == -1`.

Answer (score 1):

Step by step:  Ignore bit patterns and focus on types and values.

`0xFF` is a *integer constant* with the value of 255 and type of `int`.  (C11 §6.4.4.1 5)

`unsigned char a = 0xFF` assigned 255 to an `unsigned char` that can represent values [0-255] on your platform.  `a` gets the value of 255 and type `unsigned char`.  6.3.1.3 1

`char b = 0xFF;` assigned 255 to an `char` that, on your platform  can represent values [-128 - 127].  The value is converted in an *implementation defined* manner. 
 In OP's case, 256 is subtracted and  `b` gets the value of -1 and type `char`. 6.3.1.3 3

When these are compared to 0, the values do not change, yet they are promoted to `int`.  §6.3.1.1 2

Of course, -1 < 0, 255 > 0 and -1 != 255.

Answer (score -1):

A signed integer uses the most significant bit to store a negative number so in hardware-level-logic, you have asked:

IF (-1 != 255){
    THEN // ALWAYS RUNS
}